# Liquibase maven update fails on second attempt

Tags: maven-3, liquibase

I'm trying to create a table (if not exists) to a remote database (postgres in docker container). The sql command is located in a sql file. 
When I execute

```
mvn liquibase:update
```

by hand (bash terminal) everything works great. The build is a success and the message for the creation of the table is displayed. 
Now if I delete the table and execute the same command, then although I'm seeing a success message for the completion of the task, the table is not created (of course the message about the creation of the table is not displayed either).

As I've mentioned the database is in a docker container. So it is a remote database. I've already included the below command in my `pom.xml`

```
<promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is this changeset run with "runAllways" mode? If not, than when you are running it first time change is applied and recorded as applied and it is not executed second time at all (and there is no difference how you are running it).

Comment: I didn't know about this one. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: @dbf Sorry for the delay. You are correct. Can you please post your answer so I can accept it? Although SteveDonie provided an answer, this was after your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this changeset run with "runAllways" mode? If not, than when you are running it first time change is applied and recorded as applied and it is not executed second time at all (and there is no difference how you are running it).

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase keeps track of the changes it has applied in a separate table called DATABASECHANGELOG. If you manually delete the table (let's call this one "MyTable")  as described  above, and then re-run Liquibase, it just checks the DATABASECHANGELOG table to see if the change mentioned has been run, and if it has, it will not re-run it. If you want to see the table get re-created you would have to manually remove the row from DATABASECHANGELOG, or else (as the comment above suggests) mark the changeset in the changelog as "runAlways". Typically you do NOT want runAlways to be set because then Liquibase will try to do things like create a table that already exists.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This was the issue in the end, but @dbf provided a solution first, so in order to be fair, if he/she provides an answer I'm going to accept that. I've already upvoted though. Thanks again.